# Leadconvert setOpportunityId() not public?

Tags: apex, leads, lead-conversion

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_dml_convertLead.htm#apex_Database_LeadConvert_setOpportunityId) says it should be public, but getting an error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
> setOpportunityId(Id) from the type Database.LeadConvert

Any ideas why this method wouldn't be available?

Sample example:

```
Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity();
insert newOpp;

Database.LeadConvert leadConvertCls = new Database.LeadConvert();

//This works fine
leadConvertCls.setLeadId(myLead.Id);

//Error when saving to org:
//Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setOpportunityId(Id) from the type Database.LeadConvert (186:28)
leadConvertCls.setOpportunityId(newOpp.Id);

Database.LeadConvertResult conversionResult = Database.convertLead(leadConvertCls);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a lead to a new opportunity in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/323547/how-to-convert-a-lead-to-a-new-opportunity-in-apex)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include the relevant code and context.  Note that if the `id` parameter is null, you will get this error.

Comment: @identigral I'm confused as to why you think that's a related question (other than it hitting the keywords "lead" and "convert").

Comment: Can you please post atleast the code snippet where you are facing the issue. I have used this method earlier and didn't find any issues.

Comment: @SarojBera I added a code snippet to the question. Hopefully that provides some additional detail!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method has not always been available; it was added in [Spring 18](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm&type=5&release=212). Please check your Apex class' API version, and set it to at least version 42.0. You can find this setting in the Developer Console when you open the class, or in the *ClassName*.cls-meta.xml file in a SFDX repository or MDAPI repository.

Comment: There it is! I completely forgot that this is an older API version. Thank you!

Comment: @Austin yeah, we've all done that at least once. Comes with the territory.